# how to add header in gridview , i have written code but not working

Tags: asp.net

i want to add one header above the grid view. i have written code but header is not displaying

```
protected void GVKeywordReport_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    GridView HeaderGrid = (GridView)sender;
    GridViewRow HeaderGridRow = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Insert);
    TableCell HeaderCell = new TableCell();
    HeaderCell.Text = "hjhjhjh";
    HeaderCell.ColumnSpan = 10;
    HeaderGridRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell);
}
```

Comment: You haven't added the `HeaderGridRow` to the grid.

Comment: thanks i got it , but how to add background color to header ?

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/xxm3l40cd/
kindly see my error, link has given to see my error, Instead of 1 header im getting 5 headers.kindly  reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your HeaderGridRow to the Gridview:

```
 GridView1.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(0, HeaderGridRow );
```

Comment: how to give background color to the Header ? tried this but not worked
   HeaderCell.BackColor = "red";

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/xxm3l40cd/
i m getting 5 headers instead of 1 ...kindly check link ?

Comment: solved my error
added  if( GVKeywordReport.Controls[0].Controls.Count==0)
            {
            GVKeywordReport.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(0, HeaderGridRow);
            }

Answer (score 0):

i have writtn code in data row bound

```
 protected void GVKeywordReport_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)


         {
      if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
                {
                    int NumCells = e.Row.Cells.Count;
                    for (int i = 0; i < NumCells - 1; i++)
                    {
                        e.Row.Cells[i].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
                    }
                }
        }
```